# Creating two dimensional array of size 66000 X 66000 in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I am trying to create a graph adjacency list with size 66000 X 66000 in C++ inside a class, so I cannot use the C++11 auto feature to create the array. Also, when I tried  int *array = new int[66000*66000], which was something I saw in another stack overflow to put it on the heap, I got a integer overflow error. Is there a way in which I can create an array of this size? Thanks.

Comment: If this is for a graph adjacency list, you probably want a “sparse array” instead of a normal array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say all these 66000 * 66000 are `int`s, then it will consume about 66000 * 66000 * 4 / 2^30 = 16G memory. Do you really want to do this?

Comment: You should also state that for your calculation you are assuming that `sizeof(int)` is 4 as an `int` could be smaller or larger than that.

Answer (score 4):

The overflow you mentioned is due to the fact that `66000 * 66000` does not fit in `int` in our case.

It is questionable if having such a huge array is a good idea. But if you want, you could *try* `long long`:

```
int *array = new int[66000LL * 66000];
```

although it might exceed the maximum allowed array size on your system, see e.g. [Compiler Error C2148](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0z0bbfe.aspx).

Again, you could try using `malloc` instead. But even with `char` instead of `int` (which should be enough for adjacency), be ready to see quite unresponsive system.

Comment: `long` and `int` are normally the same size.  I would suggest `LL` for a `long long` literal.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're building a Graph Adjacency List, I'm guessing that:

1. the value for each element will be 1 (nodes connected by an edge) or 0 (nodes not connected by an edge), and
2. the array will be "sparse" (meaning, most values in the array will be 0), and
3. the array will also be symmetric, unless you're working with a Directed Graph

So rather than storing the adjacency information as a 2D array, you could save space by storing "only the 1s" of the array, e.g. as a list of (x,y) pairs.

For more information, see:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array

Comment: The graph is actually complete, but I think we are expected to "prune" the edges and remove ones that we are clearly not going to use.

Comment: Well, then you could invert the arrangement I describe and store only the set of "pruned" edges.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to store the adjacency matrix as a bitmap, since each value is either 0 or 1. This would have the advantage of saving space, and the disadvantage of making it more complicated to extract information about the connectedness of a pair of nodes.

Such a bitmap would occupy 66000 * 66000 bits, or 544500000 bytes, or about 519.3Mb. You could store it in a [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) (which is part of the [C++ STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library)).